# ng-resource url parameter does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

$resource is not correctly passing along a url parameter when making a PUT request, via custom action.

This is my service creating the resource.

```
.factory('cartItemsService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/cart/:cartId/items/', {format: 'json'}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: true},
    });
}])
```

In my controller I'm trying to update the list of items like this. Note that `$scope.cart.id` exists and is correct (in this case 1)

```
$scope.cartItems = cartItemsService.update({cartId: $scope.cart.id});
```

However the request URL is: `/api/cart/items/` but I'm expecting `/api/cart/1/items/`. This works fine if I do `.get({cartId: <some_id>})` but doesn't seem to work for update.

EDIT: Angular version 1.1.5

Comment: What happens if you hardcode and try `update({cartId:1})`?

Comment: @Chandermani, exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was due to the request headers I was setting before making the request.

I was attempting to set `put` headers like such:

```
$http.defaults.headers.put['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

This is what caused the request url to be incorrectly formatted.

Changed it to set the post header instead, and it worked.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```